# The .show method not working in a jQuery conditional while console.log reveals the the objects are present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The HTML involved is:

```
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">
     <div style="float:left;margin-left:5px;">

      <!-- for nested order-table -->
      <table class="order-table changeLogs" style="width: 472px;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Original Value</th>
            <th>Changed To</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

          [% FOREACH changeLog IN PO.changeLogs %]
          <tr id="change_order_entries">      
            <td>[%date.format(changeLog.ts, '%m/%d/%y   %l:%M %p')%]</td>
            <td>[%changeLog.nameFirst%] [%changeLog.nameLast%]</td>
            <td>[%changeLog.field%]</td>
            <td>[%changeLog.oldValue%]</td>
            <td>[%changeLog.newValue%]</td>
          </tr>
          [% END %]

        </tbody>
```

The associated function contains this conditional:

```
function showMoreChangeLogs() {

      var revealed = 0;

   $('.order-table tbody tr').each(function() {    

       if ( revealed < 10) {
              $('.order-table tr:lt(11)').show();  
               //console.log($(this));
              revealed++;
        }
        console.log(revealed);
   });
}
```

The `$('.order-table tr:lt(11)').show();` displays nothing while the console.log reveals the the objects are there in the table. Have stared at this a long time, trying various ways to get tis to display table data that is already present before posting this question.

Comment: Why do you need the `.each` loop? You're not doing anything with the elements you're looping over.

Comment: I don't think it should affect this problem, but you can't repeat `id="change_order_entries"` on each row. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: What does your rendered output look like? For example, how many rows are actually rendered out?

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4n1Lf1oa/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.order-table tr:lt(11)').show();
```

change to

```
$('.order-table tbody tr:lt(11)').show();
```

Comment: Why should that make a difference? `.order-table tr` matches all `tr` inside `.order-body`, they don't have to be immediate children.

Comment: Oh, I see it. This will ignore the `tr` that's in `thead`.

Comment: The original selector will select 1 less body row, because it also selects the head row.

Comment: But the question says that the code is displaying nothing. It should still display the first 9 rows of the body, so this isn't the whole answer.